# How to update Elasticsearch ECS in Kubernetes?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I use ECS (Elastic Cloud on Kubernetes) with Azure Kubernetes service.
ECS version 1.2.1

One Elasticsearch node (in a single pod) + one Kibana node.

I need to update Elasticsearch version from 7.9 to 7.10.

I have updated Elasticsearch version in yml file and run the command:

```
kubectl apply -f elasticsearch.yaml
```

But it was not updated. Still the old Elasticsearch is running in the same pod.

How to update Elasticsearch?
Will the data be lost?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.
I have added one extra VM to the k8s cluster and operator upgraded the Elasticsearch.
It looks like there where not enough resources in the cluster to run the update.
I have added one extra Elasticsearch pod as well. Perhaps upgrade is just not working with a single Elasticsearch pod.